# How to append and style the label ,span method in react js

Tags: reactjs

when ever the socket method call i want to append a label and span method with styling , please help me thanks in advance

```
socket.on('start_call', async (customerName, Id) =>{
// here i want to append the  customerName for label and Id for span  
}
```

Comment: please explain problem.

Comment: i want to display the `customerName` and `id` in a page

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you are gonna attach `span` to `div` whose id is `div_area`.

```
socket.on('start_call', async (customerName, Id) =>{
   document.getElementById('div_area').innerHtml += `<span id=${Id}>${customerName}</span>`;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should appracoh this way (just the idea and simplified version, if you have any struggle to integrate with your code, please let me know).

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('start_call', async (name, id) => {
      setCustomers([...customers, { name, id }])
    }
  }, []) // Run once when component render, the same as `componentDidMount` on class base component

  return (
    <div>
      {customers.length > 0 && customers.map((customer) => {
        <label>{customer.name}</label>
        <span>{customer.id}</span>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: when ever other customer adds .. the previous `customerName` is removing, how to save the prevoius customer names

Comment: See my edit, my assumption is you need to render customer name and customer id a pair one by one so we should to construct the state as a object like `{ name: '', id: '' }`

Comment: i tried the above code but still getting the same , the new  `customer` is adding but previous one is removing